How to convert a When Issue US Treasury Note price expressed in yield terms to par value 100 terms
Between October 3, 2024 (announcement date) and auction date October 8, 2024 the US Treasury 3 Year Note is tradeable and trade prices are expressed in yield terms.
I need the formula to convert the trade price expressed in yield terms to par value 100 terms.
Here is an example from on a very common trading platform for cusip: 91282CLQ2
dated and issue date = 10/15/2024
trade date = 10/07/2024 
settlement date = 10/15/2024 
maturity date = 10/15/2027
assumed coupon rate = 3.5 
trade price in yield terms = 3.895 

How does the VERY COMMON trading platform I entered a trade  ticket for the above example arrive at a price in par value 100 terms = 98.891755
I have tried MANY fixed income formulas, none provide this price in par value 100 terms.

Your stated bond is very simplistic: it has no stub periods and it does not have settlement mid-period. The Yield-to-Maturity (YTM) for a bond, whose formula is stated on many different websites can be directly applied. This is @Felix answer below and he has gone through all the steps for you.

First of all, the discount rate/yield is 3.895, which is for bond principal and interests discounted. And the coupon is 3.5 which is for interest calculation. Bond tenor is 3y, so there are 6 interests payment usually treasury bond is semi-annually interest payment.
So, assume principal is 100, discount rate is 3.895, the Principal-PV is 100÷((1+(3.895%÷2))^6)= 89.07;
Interest for semi-annually payment is 100×3.5%÷2 = 1.75, there are total 6 interest payments, we need discount the all 6 interest cash flows based on the 1, 2, 3,... 6 interest periods. Eg, the 3rd one interest payment, discount the 1.75, the discount factor is 1÷((1+(3.895%÷2))^3) = 0.9438, and the 3rd interest PV is 1.75 x 0.9438 = 1.65. For all the interest cash flow PV is like below,
(Period // Interest // Discount factor // Interest PV)

1st one (1 // 1.75 // 0.9809 // 1.72),
2nd one (2 // 1.75 // 0.9622 // 1.68), 
3rd one (3 // 1.75 // 0.9438 // 1.65), 
4th one (4 // 1.75 // 0.9257 // 1.62), 
5th one (5 // 1.75 // 0.9081 // 1.59), 
6th one (6 // 1.75 // 0.8907 // 1.56). 

And the total interests PV is 9.82
Then, we have all the principal PV and interests PV, 89.07 + 9.82 = 98.89.
Finally, we have the bond face value=100, the all the repayment cash flows PV=98.89, so the issuance price is 98.89÷100×100 = 98.891755.
You could calculate it in Excel like below,


please keep the PV results as xx.xxxxxx, then you will get the exact number same as it in your question
